# Android custom fonts not working programmatically

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

I need to change my app's font to a custom font. I'm using Android Native Fonts for this. I have added my_font.ttf and my_font_italic.ttf on the font folder.

Also, I created this font family resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<font-family xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font
        android:fontStyle="normal"
        android:font="@font/my_font"
        app:fontStyle="normal"
        app:font="@font/my_font"/>

    <font
        android:fontStyle="italic"
        android:font="@font/my_font_italic"
        app:fontStyle="italic"
        app:font="@font/my_font_italic"/>
</font-family>
```

On my layout, I have a LinearLayout with a couple of TextViews like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="@style/text_28_italic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"
        android:text="Test Text"/>

    <TextView
        android:textAppearance="@style/text_28_bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="@font/my_font"
        android:text="Test Text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The styles I'm using are:

```
<style name="text_28_italic">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>

<style name="text_28_bold">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/my_font</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

If I test the app, the fonts in the text views are shown correctly.

However, the **problem** comes when I try to add TextViews by code. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html), I need to use `Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.myfont);` to set the font by code. But I also need to set a style so I'm using `setTextAppearance()` too.

Here is my code:

```
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
tv1.setText("Test text");
tv1.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.my_font));
tv1.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.text_28_italic);
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test)).addView(tv1);

TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
tv2.setText("Test text")
tv2.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.text_28_bold);
tv2.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.my_font));
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test)).addView(tv2);
```

This way, I cannot make it work. I get the font applied, but not the text appearance.

How can I make both text appearance and typeface work programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.roboto);
```

.............or........................

```
Typeface typeface = getResources.getFont(R.font.roboto);
textView.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Comment: I am getting error at R.font. Android Studio makes it red as an error.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your .ttf font to the asset folder. Then create typeface and apply it to your widget like below.

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"YourFontName.ttf"); //you can use your activity name instead of getActivity().
TextView tv = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv.setTypeface(tf);
```

To change Appearance use below code.

```
tv.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
tv.setTypeface(tv.getTypeface(),Typeface.BOLD);
```

Comment: I will try this, but this is not using Android native fonts. Is there a way for doing this using native fonts?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use the [Calligraphy Library](https://github.com/chrisjenx/Calligraphy) to set custom fonts in your app via XML like this,

> ```
> <TextView
>     android:text="@string/hello_world"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     fontPath="fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf"/>
> ```

**Custom font in TextAppearance**

> ```
> <style name="TextAppearance.FontPath" parent="android:TextAppearance">
>     <!-- Custom Attr-->
>     <item name="fontPath">fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</item>
> </style>
>
> <TextView
>     android:text="@string/hello_world"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"/>
> ```

**Custom font in Styles**

> ```
> <style name="TextViewCustomFont">
>     <item name="fontPath">fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf</item>
> </style>
> ```

**Custom font defined in Theme**

> ```
> <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
>     <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/AppTheme.Widget.TextView</item>
> </style>
>
> <style name="AppTheme.Widget"/>
>
> <style name="AppTheme.Widget.TextView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.TextView">
>     <item name="fontPath">fonts/Roboto-ThinItalic.ttf</item>
> </style>
> ```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a feasable alternative for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set style with custom fonts in a textview programmatically, this is how you can do it

```
textView?.setTextAppearance(R.style.your_style)
            textView?.typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                context.assets,
                context.getString(R.string.your_font_path))
            )
```